# Calculate time from 1 column

Tags: sql-server

Ok, here's my situation.  Our previous DB specialist (SQL Server 2008) set up a table to store times for performance purposes. The times are generated from a VB script and entered into the table.

The performance process (in table: from bottom to top):

- (open 1) selects from a menu (1) -> documents the time
- (open 2) window appears (2) -> documents the time
- (select 1) enters and account number and presses 'search' (3) -> documents the time
- (select 2) when the data appears -> documents the time (4)

e.g.

```
Msrmnt  | Time                    | Window     | Function | Position  
--------+-------------------------+------------+----------+-----------
109     | 2016-05-10 20:35:32.243 | WindowName | Select   |    2  
109     | 2016-05-10 20:35:29.230 | WindowName | Select   |    1  
109     | 2016-05-10 20:35:26.697 | WindowName | Open     |    2     
109     | 2016-05-10 20:35:23.297 | WindowName | Open     |    1
```

Now, I need to calculate the time (e.g.) between the 2 open values (1 & 2). I do have a lot of experience with DB's, but I am stuck on how I should best approach this to be sure I am 1.) getting accurate results, 2.) the calculations are efficient regarding time (as there are lot of entries within a weeks time)

Thanks for any suggestions

Karen

Comment: self join the table into itself and then you have two time columns you can work with.

Comment: If we're just working with the `Open` values and ignoring the `Select` ones, could we have more than a *single* example please? And also, can you show us what the expected *results* are. How do we relate pairs of rows (are there only ever two `Open` rows for a given `Msrmnt` value?)

Answer (score 2):

The basic example how to get calculated time between two time values:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(109, '2016-05-10 20:35:32.243', 'WindowName', 'Select', 2),
(109, '2016-05-10 20:35:29.230', 'WindowName', 'Select', 1),
(109, '2016-05-10 20:35:26.697', 'WindowName', 'Open', 2),   
(109, '2016-05-10 20:35:23.297', 'WindowName', 'Open', 1)
) as t (Msrmnt, [Time], Window, [Function], Position)
)

SELECT  c.Msrmnt,
        c.Window,
        DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,c.[Time],c1.[Time]) as ms
FROM cte c
INNER JOIN cte c1 
    ON c.Msrmnt = c1.Msrmnt 
        AND c.Window = c1.Window 
        AND c.[Function] = c1.[Function] 
        AND c.Position + 1= c1.Position
WHERE c.[Function] = 'Open'
```

Output:

```
Msrmnt      Window     ms
----------- ---------- -----------
109         WindowName 3400
```

Comment: HI gofr  Thanks for your answer . . . I've tried to implement your solution but, the thing is, I can't 'know' what the measuerment is (109: this is 109th measurement) and I can't know what the time is . . . I CAN know the window (but would rather not), function and position (@Damien... all functions apply, there are others, these are just examples) . . . I can equate e.g. measurement (c.msrmnt = c1.msrmnt),  window(s) (c.window = c1.window)  and function (c.function = c1.function) . . . can I still use this method?

Comment: I assume you need only `measurement` and time between `open` some windows and it is not important what windows, and its positions. Am I right? If so the answer would very.

Comment: And yes, you can use it, but as I say earlier, query will vary if you don't need specific window and position

Comment: Yes, the position is important as the difference is calculated between the positions 1 and 2. I am going to have another look at your solution, but I ended up using Allen's idea (Thanks Allen) -> see reply below.  Perhaps yours would be more elegent for my purpose, but I'm just not seeing it yet . . . we'll see how it develops . . . Thanks a lot for your imput!!

Comment: You can simply try my solution simply changing `cte` in query on your table name. :) And remove part `;WITH cte as (.... )`

Answer (score 2):

Base on the date order in SQL 2008. If the platform is SQL 2012 then this can be LEAD or LAG function.

```
;WITH X AS (

SELECT 109 AS Msrmnt, CAST('2016-05-10 20:35:32.243' AS DATETIME) As Date, 'WindowName' AS Window,  'Select' AS [Function],   2 AS Position UNION ALL   
SELECT 109,CAST('2016-05-10 20:35:29.230' AS DATETIME),'WindowName' , 'Select',1  UNION ALL
SELECT 109,CAST('2016-05-10 20:35:26.697' AS DATETIME),'WindowName','Open',2     UNION ALL 
SELECT 109,CAST('2016-05-10 20:35:23.297' AS DATETIME),'WindowName','Open',1 
)
SELECT 
 DATEDIFF(S,x1.Date, x2.Date)
 ,x1.Date, x2.Date
FROM x as x1
 INNER JOIN x as x2 
  ON x1.Msrmnt = x2.Msrmnt AND x1.Window = x2.Window AND x1.Date < x2.Date 
WHERE x1.[Function] = 'Open' AND x2.[Function] = 'Open'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it like this . . .

```
Select t.ZP1, t.Form1, t.ZP2, t.Form2, DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,t.ZP1,t.ZP2) as ms  
From  
(Select p1.time as ZP1, p1.window as Form1, p2.time as ZP2, p2.window as Form2
from tpermonitor p1 LEFT JOIN   
tpermonitor p2 On 
p2.msrmnt = p1.msrmnt 
and p2.Funktion = 'open' 
and p2.Position = 2 and p2.System = 'mysys'  
and p2.time Between '05.04.2016' and '05.13.2016'   
and p2.window = p1.window and p2.msrmnt = p1.msrmnt   
where  p1.System like 'mysys'  
and p1.time Between '05.04.2016' and '05.13.2016'   
and p1.Position = 1  
and p1.Funktion like 'Open'  
and CAST(p2.time as DATE) = CAST(p1.time as DATE)) as t  
Order by t.ZP1
```

I'm not sure it's the prettiest solution, but it works.  Will work on a more elegant solution in the future, but for the time being, I'll work with this.

If anyone wishes to comment, I'm open . . .

Thanks for all your feedback